# How to compare with Comparator.comparing?

Tags: java, comparator

Hi, i want to compare and get the max date. My problem is the next one:

i got this codeline:

```
    Optional<User> userOptional = users.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(User::getStudent::getDate));
```

This is how my entites are:

```
User{

    Long id;
    Student student;
    ...
}

Student{
    Long id;
    Date startDate;
    ...
}
```

And i want to get the user with the starDate more recent.

Thanks.

Comment: `comparing(u -> u.getStudent().getDate())`

Comment: You should post the error message when asking questions like this. It might even give you hints what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot chain two method references. Use lambda instead:

```
Optional<User> userOptional = users.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(user -> user.getStudent().getDate()));
```